# ignore special characters at the end in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to split a comma separated list into groups, with this regex:
`/(?<k>[\d.]+)\s(?<i>[\w\d\p{L}\s\/.-]+(?:\(.*?\))?)/gu`

For example it splits up "34 bananas, 12 l. applejuice." into

```
[0][k] = 34; [i] = bananas
[1][k] = 12; [i] = l. applejuice.
```

At the end of the text is a dot `.` which will be recognized as a part of the text. Since some parts *can* have a dot inside of it, like `l.` (the shortcut of `liters` does) i needed to implement it, too. But i don't need it at the end.

For a better explanation please see [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Sw43OQ/10).

In short: i need to ignore every comma `,` and dot `.` at the end of every value, but need to have inside of the strings.
I tried it like `[^,.]` at the end, but it doesn't work. `(?!,|\.)` at the end or the beginning doesn't work aswell.

Comment: `[\w\d\p{L}\s\/.-]+[\w\d\p{L}\s\/-]` should do the trick (i.e. the last character cannot be a `.`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunatly it doesn't since match 17 still doesn't split up. Can i tell regex "if a dot `.` or a comma `,` has a blank behind it and it isn't inside of brackets then cut it"?

Comment: How are you invoking that? For example if I simply do `"yourSampleString".split(yourRegex)` I get 7 array elements in the result, not what you are showing as `[0][k]...etc`

Answer (score 0):

You might use a negative lookbehind asserting what is directly to the left is not a dot.

`\w` will also match `\d` but as you use `\p{L}` to match any kind of letter, you might omit`\w` and add an underscore (which is matched by `\w`)

```
/(?<k>[\d.]+)\s(?<i>[\p{L}\d_\s\/.-]+(?<!\.)(?:\([^()]*\))?)/gu
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yucz1Z/1)

```js
let s = `34 bananas, 12 l. applejuice., Zusätzlich benötigte Fahrzeuge: 43 FuStW, 93 Löschfahrzeuge (LF), 86.375 l. Wasser, 300 l. Löschschaum, 25 Drehleitern (DLK 23), 2 FwK, 2 GW-A oder AB-Atemschutz, 10 Gerätekraftwagen (GKW), 10 THW-Einsatzleitung (MTW TZ), 1 Schlauchwagen (GW-L2 Wasser, SW 1000, SW 2000 oder Ähnliches), 10 ELW 1, 2 Dekon-P, 25 ELW 2, 1 GW-Messtechnik, 1 GW-Gefahrgut, 1 GW-Höhenrettung, 1 Rettungshundestaffel/n. Wir benötigen mindestens 12 Feuerwehrleute.`;
let pattern = /(?<k>[\d.]+)\s(?<i>[\p{L}\d_\s\/.-]+(?<!\.)(?:\([^()]*\))?)/gu
console.log(s.match(pattern));
```